# click area smaller after rotateY

Tags: css, rotation, click, area

i have this very simple case

http://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/misyj

html

```
<body>
  <div class="below"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
</body>
```

css

```
html, body
  height: 100%
  width: 100%

body
  perspective: 3000px

.below
  height: 100%
  width: 100%
  background-color: #000
  position: absolute


.top
  background-color: #ff0000
  position: absolute
  top: 10em
  left: 10em
  width: 200px
  height: 200px
  transform-origin: 80% 0%
  transform: rotateY(-50deg)
```

js

```
  $(".below").on("click", function(){
    console.log("below")
  })

  $(".top").on("click", function(){
   console.log("top")
  })
```

if you click on the red(.top) shape you will see the clickevent of the .below is fired note the .top

only if you click around 10-20px from the right at the red shape the .top clickevent get fired

does somebody know why? and how i can fix that?

i have tested that in chrome Version 28.0.1500.72 m

in firefox the click area is bigger on the red shape. it just fires the wrong event if you click at the very left side of the red shape.

Comment: sorry but is suppose to happen to the red object?

Comment: if i click anywhere on the red object it should fire the clickevent, and you should see in the console "top"

open your console and then click on the red object the way i  
described above